# JPA,detaching parent entity and fill in child entity

Tags: jpa

I am using JPA in google app engine project development.I have an entity(Order) in many side of an one to many relationship with Customer entity.The mapping field(customer) is annotated with Fetchtype Lazy.While trying to retrieve an order entity ans send it to client I am not able to properly fill the customer field in the order entity. There is problem in detachment. How can I detach the customer entity and send it as a field of order entity? em.detach() is not available.

Answer (score 0):

are you using ejb? or some kind of transaction boundary?

calling getter explicitely should populate the entity

detachment will happen automatically once transaction is over

what exactly is the issue you are facing, do you have code and stack trace?